# how to exclude content from html page and keeping only the html tags?

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a huge corpus of HTML pages and I want to exclude all the content from this dataset and finally extracting only the html tags(I want the tags, not the contents). For instance if i have this html elements:

```
<div class="tensorsite-content__title  ">
      Differentiate yourself with the TensorFlow Developer Certificate    </div>
```

I need to extract only  :

```
 <div class="tensorsite-content__title  ">
           </div>
```

I have tried the (?!) negative lookahead regex to exclude the html tags matches with

`tags=re.sub('.*?!<[^<]+?>', '',htmlwithcontent )`

but despite the fact it doesn't look smart and efficient, obviously, it doesn't work even!

So do you have any Idea? preferably in python

Comment: [Have you tried using a parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/479156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivar commented, an HTML parser is really the only way to correctly deal with this class of problem:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.indent = -1

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.indent += 1
        print(2 * self.indent * ' ', sep='', end='')
        print(f'<{tag}', sep='', end='')
        for attr in attrs:
            print(f' {attr[0]}="{attr[1]}"', sep='', end='')
        print('>', sep='')

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print(2 * self.indent * ' ', sep='', end='')
        print(f'</{tag}>')
        self.indent -= 1

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed("""<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Heading!</h1>
    <p style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
       Some text
       <BR/>
       Some more text
    </p>
    <ol>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
     </ol>
  </body>
</html>
""")
```

Prints:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
    </h1>
    <p style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
      <br>
      </br>
    </p>
    <ol>
      <li>
      </li>
      <li>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

[See Python Demo](https://ideone.com/4PU846)

**Update**

If the HTML is is a not-too-large file, it make sense to read the entire file into memory and pass to the parser thus:

```
parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open('test.html') as f:
    html = f.read()
    parser.feed(html)
```

If the input is in a extremely large file, it might make sense to "feed" the parser line by line or in chunks rather than attempting to read the entire file into memory:

**Line by Line:**

```
parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open('test.html') as f:
    for line in f:
        parser.feed(line)
```

Or even more efficiently:

**To Read in Chunks of 32K:**

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 32 * 1024
parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open('test.html') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if chunk == '':
            break
        parser.feed(chunk)
```

You can, of course, choose even larger chunk sizes.

Comment: thank you so much, but do you have any suggestions for a more efficient way in a huge corpus?

Comment: I updated my answer. It's not clear whether you have lots of normal size HTML files or one very large HTML file that is a composed of these smaller HTML files, so I have included code to handle both situations.